# Functions as Arguments: Exercise

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some exercises in order to do a javascript intensive bootcamp and I'm stuck with this exercise. Really hope that you guys can help this mega noob.

The exercise:

> Declare the variable add and assign it a function which takes two
>   arguments, operand1 and operand2, and returns the sum of those
>   arguments.
>
> Declare the variable calculate and assign it a function which takes
>   three arguments, operand1, operand2 and operation.
>
> Inside the body of calculate, invoke the function passed as the
>   argument operation, passing as arguments operand1 and operand2, and
>   print the result of this invocation to the console.
>
> Don't forget to invoke calculate passing it the add function as a
>   third argument.

Result so far: >>>>Code is incorrect
Create a variable in the body of the calculate function to invoke the function received as argument

```js
var add = function(operand1, operand2) {
  return operand1 + operand2;
};

var calculate = function(operand1, operand2, operation) {
  var result = operation(operand1, operand2);
  console.log(result);
};
```

Comment: have you tried it? what does not work with it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you want to add further information to your post, please click the edit button and add the information to the question rather than adding it as a comment

Comment: And even better: Click the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Rob_da_Bank we need you to try youyr code, then tell us what does not work

Comment: Not seeing an expected `if (operation == )`

Comment: please add **all** information to the question and not in the comments section.

Comment: Hey @NinaScholz, the only stuff I didn't add on the question was the result after executing the code that I've written in my previous comment. The rest is all there in the post question. But I gotcha ;)

Comment: The question says that now, you need to create a function that can take 3 params. the first two will be operands and the third a operation. First you try to complete this step, before moving forward.

Comment: var calculate = function (operand1, operand2, operation) { 
  var result = operation(operand1, operand2);
  console.print(result)
}

Comment: Please UPDATE THE QUESTION!

Comment: And call the function  - otherwise nothing will happen

Comment: you'll also want to use `console.log()` rather than `console.print()`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Now all you need to do is _invoke calculate passing it the add function as a third argument._ Click edit, scroll down and click _edit above snippet_

Comment: Hey @mplungjan, that's precisely my problem, I don't know how I should add function as a third argument. I'm really new at all this and I must do these exercises in order to start learning properly :(

Comment: You know from your math lessons what an operand is? So if you need to add something, you can pass two numbers (operands) and the function you just made

Comment: @Rob_da_Bank You were very close. You just need to call your calculate with two operands and the operation you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
var add = function(operand1, operand2) {
    return operand1 + operand2;
}

var calculate = function(operand1, operand2, operation) {
    console.log(operation(operand1, operand2));
}
```

Try adding this to the end of your code:

```
calculate(4, 4, add);
```

In the console, output is 8.

Comment: That is not helping him. You are just making his homework for him

Comment: Tks Aryamaan but mplungjan is right. I need to get there by myself. Yes the result is 8 but its still telling me that I should "Create a variable in the body of the calculate function to invoke the function received as argument", and that is precisely where I'm stuck and don't know how to do :(

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand that.